How to Create a Popup Animation for a Like Button in Android using Kotlin?
How to Create a Popup Animation for a Like Button in Android using Kotlin?
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Used ObjectAnimator to change the button’s scale when clicked.
Added an onClickListener to trigger the animation.

However, the animation doesn’t look as smooth or impactful as I’d like. Is there a way to chain animations or make this pop effect smoother? Should I use something other than ObjectAnimator or tweak the timing?
I want the button to "pop" smoothly when clicked, creating a satisfying feedback effect for the user.

I've tried this way and it work me.
  fun animateLikeButton(likeButton: ImageView, context: Context) {
        val scaleUpX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(likeButton, "scaleX", 1f, 1.4f)
        val scaleUpY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(likeButton, "scaleY", 1f, 1.4f)

        val scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(likeButton, "scaleX", 1.4f, 1f)
        val scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(likeButton, "scaleY", 1.4f, 1f)

        val scaleUpSet = AnimatorSet().apply {
            playTogether(scaleUpX, scaleUpY)
            duration = 150
        }

        val scaleDownSet = AnimatorSet().apply {
            playTogether(scaleDownX, scaleDownY)
            duration = 150
        }

        scaleDownSet.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation)
                likeButton.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        context, R.drawable.ic_like_filled
                    )
                )

            }
        })

        AnimatorSet().apply {
            playSequentially(scaleUpSet, scaleDownSet)
            start()
        }
    } 

i hope it would solve your problem.
